# Using proportional constraints results in glitches on different screen sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I've come across this issue while working on a bigger project, but I've simplified it to demonstrate the problem.

I have a UIView in my View Controller that is square and centered:

[image]
[image]

Now, 'Proportional Height' is important here, because the problem does not occur if height or width are set to constant:

[image]

I want this view to appear as a nice circle on the phone, so I add an outlet from it to ViewController.swift and provide `cornerRadius` to view's `layer`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var centerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centerView.layer.cornerRadius = centerView.frame.width / 2
    }

}
```

When in my Storyboard I set 'View as' to iPhone SE and launch the app on iPhone SE simulator, I get the expected result:

[image]
[image]

But if I do not change 'View as' in Storyboard and launch on iPhone 6 Plus simulator, this is what I get:

[image]
[image]

When I change Storyboard to corresponding screen, it's back to normal:

[image]
[image]

I was hoping it's just a Simulator bug, but same problem occurs when launching on physical devices. So potentially when the app is deployed, users may get messed up UI depending on which screen I chose for my Storyboard while developing?

**UPDATE**. I should note that adding `layoutIfNeeded()` to ViewController file resolves the issue:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
    centerView.layer.cornerRadius = centerView.frame.width / 2
}
```

But shouldn't layout happen without forcing when app launches no matter on which screen size?

Comment: Move `centerView.layer.cornerRadius = centerView.frame.width / 2` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. In `viewDidLoad` the view's size will be whatever it is in the storyboard or xib. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called after the view's frame has updated.

Answer (score 1):

Views can change size frequently. If you set the `.cornerRadius` in `viewDidLoad()` it won't be reflected if the view changes.

You will be much better off subclassing your `UIView`:

```
class RoundedView: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.height / 2.0
    }
}
```

and, you can easily make it "designable" so you see the "round view" when laying it out in your storyboard:

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedView: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.height / 2.0
    }
}
```